# How well do random forest models work for longitudinal data problems?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

My dataset is currently longitudinal (i.e. each day for each city represents a data observation) but I will reshape it so that each of the 15 days that the model is going to use will be covariates/independent variables. Hence each row represents a trainable observation encoding the last 15 days of data up to that day.

I want to build a model that takes the last 15 days of weather as input and predicts the next 15 days, for each city. In particular, I want to train a multi-output random forest model, but I'm not sure how well-suited it is for a longitudinal data problem that is transformed as a sequence of covariates.

Comment: This could work, or it could not, nobody can answer this based on this information alone.

Comment: @user2974951 i want to understand the statistical implication of transforming longitudinal datasets as a sequence of covariates for ML models. it's not a subjective question